# jQuery Touchscreen Slideout Keyboard

Tags: jquery, keyboard, touchscreen, keypad

I am creating a touchscreen application to use popups for certain pieces of information.  I need a touchscreen keyboard that will work in these popups & only appear when the input fields are in focus.

I will have a username and password field.  When I touch the text box to enter this information, the keyboard should appear (similar to a mobile device such as iPhone). I don't want it to popup on top of everything; instead I would like it to slide into view and have the popup modal window grow.  I've looked into many options including [Github Keyboard](http://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/).  My concern with that solution was that there is a known issue with the capslock not working properly.

I've also seen [Keith Wood's Keypad](http://keith-wood.name/keypad.html), but not sure how that could work if there are 2 input fields.  I have been trying to find a slick jquery opensource plugin.

Comment: why not rely on the native keyboard on the touch device?

Comment: This is not for a mobile device.  It's a touchscreen application that will run on Windows7, IE9 in full screen mode.  Sort of like a walkup kiosk.  We'll have to build the keyboard into our application.